# Ranking Search Results in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

This might have a very easy solution but I am just starting to learn so I don't know.

I have a database of some chemical data where I have 2 columns of interest in search:

1. Compound Name -> Have one compound name (1 to 5 words) in each
2. Compound Synonym (up to 200 different words) in each

The 1 contains the name of the compound and the 2 contains the synonyms for the compound.
I made a vector column for these two columns with this:

```
   alter table compound
    add column document_vector_weights tsvector;
   update compound
   set document_vector_weights = setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(cmpdname, '')), 'A') ||
    setweight(to_tsvector(cmpdsynonym), 'D');
   CREATE INDEX document_weights_index
        on compound
        USING GIN (document_vector_weights)
```

As you can see that I want the name of the compound to have the most amount of weight.

The problem is that i.e.
I am searching for the term "propylene" which is a compound and I get the following result:

[image: Result Table]

"Propylene glycol" and "Propylene carbonate" are appearing before the "Propylene" itself. This is happening because the term "propylene" is present multiple times in the synonyms column of those two compounds even though their weight is a 'D'.

I want to put in a condition that --> if the exact search term appears in the "name" column then it should be the one at the top of the rank no matter how many times it appears in other columns.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

***EDIT:***

Sample Data - here "|||" is a column separator
This is the result I am getting where searching for the term `Propylene` puts it on rank 3. I want it on rank one.

```
compounddname ||| compoundsynonym
"Propylene glycol" ||| 1,2-propanediol|propylene glycol|propane-1,2-diol|57-55-6|1,2-Propylene glycol| ...etc
"Propylene carbonate" ||| PROPYLENE CARBONATE|108-32-7|4-Methyl-1,3-dioxolan-2-one|1,2-Propylene carbonate|1,2-Propanediol cyclic carbonate|...etc
"Propylene" ||| PROPYLENE|Propene|1-Propene|Methylethylene|prop-1-ene|Methylethene|1-Propylene|...etc
"1-Methoxy-2-propanol" ||| 1-Methoxy-2-propanol|107-98-2|1-Methoxypropan-2-ol|Methoxyisopropanol|PGME|...etc
"Poloxalene" ||| Poloxalene|Poloxamer 188|Pluronic|Poloxalkol|9003-11-6|Poloxamer 407|Pluronic L 61|...etc
```

As you can see in the first two rows (synonyms of "Propylene glycol" and "Propylene carbonate") that the term "propylene" appears multiple times in the `compoundsynonym` column. This affects the ranking results.

What I want it => If I search for the term `Propylene` and an exact match is found in the `compoundname` column then the weighing system should not affect it's rankings and it should have rank 1 because it is perfect match in the name of any compound. Right now it gets ranking 3. This happenes because the term `Propylene` is available multiple times in the `compoundsynonym` column of the first two compounds that rank.

You can see if I copy and paste that first synonym cell it looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Skl.png)

Comment: It seems easy to fix, but I can't really understand the exact issue. Can you add a few rows of sample (minimal) data in text form, and the expected result of the search?

Comment: @TheImpaler Hey, I added more info about the problem. I hope that this would help you understand. Thank you for replying. If this doesn't help then I can make a video explaining the problem.

Comment: @TheImpaler I was looking through https://pganalyze.com/blog/full-text-search-django-postgres and saw that I can set the value of weights by myself. I think that is the solution to this problem.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem by altering the default values of A, B, C, and D while ranking the results.
This is how I did it:

```
 select *, ts_rank( '{0,0,0.10,1}', document_vector_weights, plainto_tsquery('propylene')) as rank_a
 from compound where document_vector_weights @@ plainto_tsquery('propylene')
 order by rank_a desc;
```

Here `{0,0,0.10,1}` are the values of D, C, B, and A respectively.
I reduced the value of `D` to `0` so the name of the compound will have the most weight.